# Is this scream from Majora's Mask?

Tags: zelda-majoras-mask

I've been playing Runner 3, and there's a track in the first world that's full of sound effects, some of which sound very familiar. In particular, [there's a scream one minute in](https://youtu.be/rmF2HA04THc?t=1m) that reminds me a lot of Legend of Zelda: Majora's Mask.

Can anyone confirm that this is indeed sampled from Majora's Mask, and if possible, tell me when it occurs in the game? Thanks!

(P.S. If you recognise any other sound effects, that'd be awesome too! I got some Croc 2 vibes from some of them, but I couldn't match them to the game.)

Comment: I've reopened this question as it's very similar to [this open question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/327655/which-games-sound-effects-feature-in-the-song-floating-above-the-earth-by-the). I'd ask any user who think this or the other question should be closed to please make a meta before casting any new close votes. Thanks!

Comment: This question is being discussed on Meta: https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13068/where-do-we-stand-on-artifacts-the-asker-believes-are-from-a-game?noredirect=1#comment41448_13068

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it's likely not.

If you listen to the scream, there's a lot of clipping and blowout on the sample, which leads me to believe that it was recorded on an older or low-quality mic (cell phone camera, for example). The few screams in Majora's Mask are all well-balanced and high quality. Don't know where the sample would have come from but I highly doubt it's lodged anywhere in MM.

The scream you might be thinking of might be the scream you hear when you put on a mask.

Comment: I was thinking that this was the scream in question. However, these were all too short. From distant memory, I thought there were some longer screams in Majora's Mask? Anyway, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score -1):

That is a stock Tarzan sound - no idea where it came from. However, I thought when I heard it that it sounded like the Four Giants from Majora's Mask, and when I went to do some digging, I found this thread! So, it most likely is in Majora's Mask; or at least part of it is.